# Every absolute retract (AR) is contractible

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

This is homework.

I need to show that every AR is contractible.

All I can basically do here is list definitions:

A space $Y$ is AR if: $X$ is metrizable, $A$ is closed subset of $X$ and $f: A \mapsto Y$ is continuous, then $f$ has a continuous extension $g: X \mapsto Y$.

A space $Y$ is contractible if $id_Y :Y \mapsto Y$ is homotopic to a constant map.

I was thinking if I could use the fact that every AR is path connected and also every contractible space is path connected.

Comment: Every contractible space is path-connected, but very few path-connected spaces are contractible.

Comment: Hint: Let X be the $Y \times I$ but collapse $Y \times \{1\}$ to a point.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact definition you are given for AR? Don't you imbed X into Y, from memory, and X is the a deformation retract of Y, or something like that?

Comment: @gnometorule Yes, that is given as an "alternative" definition in my book.

Comment: an AR is a metric space by definition. The hint given by Hagen von Eitzen is the correct way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a continuous function 
$$h\colon Y\times[0,1]\to Y$$
and $y_0\in Y$ such that $h(y,0)=y$ and $h(y,1)=y_0$. 
Thus it suggests itself to let $X=Y\times[0,1]$ and $A=Y\times\{0,1\}$.
Of course $A$ is closed in the product topology because $Y$ is closed in $Y$ and $\{0,1\}$ is closed in $[0,1]$.
There "only" remains the question whether $X$ is metrizable. Can you take over from there?

Comment: Well, $Y$ was AR and closed interval is AR also and the countable product of AR is AR, so X is AR... But I doubt that AR implies metrizable. I have a theorem that if $X$ can be embedded to a Hilbert's cube, $X$ is metrizable. I must think this some more.

Comment: Nope, I cannot really see way to prove $X$ would be metrizable. All the theorems I have seem to demand $X$ to be second countable and regular or so and I can't figure why this would be. If we, however, assume $X$ is metrizable, I think if we define $h(y,0)=y$ and $h(y,1)=y_0$, this is continuous as $h(y,0)$ is identity and  $h(y,1)$ is constant, so the preimages stay closed. And it would have the continuous extension, which gives the required properties.

Comment: Stupid me... is says that AR is metrizable on the book, in one word which I managed to skip over numerous times... after that, it is more or less trivial. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AR are metrizable. In fact AR = AR(M) = M intersect with ES(M) where M = class of metric spaces and ES(M) class of absolute extensors for metric spaces, AR(M) = absolute retracts for metric spaces..