# homotopy between continuous functions to an absolute retract

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the following statement to prove as one of the "fundamental" questions our topology professor wants us to know for his final:

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A$ be an absolute retract.  Suppose $f,g:X\to A$ are continuous functions.  Show that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

I've attempted to make use of things like Urysohn's lemma (since the definition of absolute retract applies for normal spaces $Y$ such that $A\subseteq Y$ and $A$ is closed in Y), but that was a dead end, and I'm having trouble thinking of other possible routes.  My topology professor also likes to sometimes leave important information out or leave things ambiguous, so the statement as-is may not even be true.  In the case that it's true, what's a possible starting point?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307261/every-absolute-retract-ar-is-contractible